# Disable piece of jQuery for Safari only

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

Is it possible to disable a piece of jQuery for Safari only? Having issues getting it to work correctly due to Safari loading the cached page when you click "back" so i just want to disable it completely in Safari only.

```
  jQuery(".hometext").click(function() {
    jQuery(this).toggleClass("slide");
    jQuery(".hometext").toggleClass("active");
        jQuery("#header-elementor").toggleClass("active");
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something below.

```js
if (
    navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') != -1 && 
    navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') == -1 && 
    navigator.userAgent.indexOf('CriOS/') == -1
){ 
    
    
    console.log('applied code to only safari');
} else {
   console.log('applied code except safari');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks, are you able to add my code above into that as im not sure where to put it

Comment: replace your code with => console.log('applied code except safari');